# How to auto generate sound code if data increases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

I have person data that contain dynamic boolean value. The value is generated automatically and can be true or false every time.

Webpage get the data every 5 seconds and render it. If the value on each person is false then the sound is played.

I have problem if the data increases, i must add manually code to render and play a sound.

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Sound from './Mp3';

const data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'peter',
    value: true
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'john',
    value: false
  }
];

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    results: [],
    playSoundPeter: false,
    playSoundJohn: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData()
    // get data every 5 sec
    setInterval(this.getData, 5000);
  }

  getData = () => {
    // generate random value
    data[0].value = Math.random() >= 0.5;
    data[1].value = Math.random() >= 0.5;

    // set results state to data
    this.setState({ results: data });

    // extract array results
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.results.length; i++) {
      // set playSoundPeter state to true if
      // data value equal to false & vice versa
      if (this.state.results[0].value === false) {
        this.setState({ playSoundPeter: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ playSoundPeter: false });
      }

      // set playSoundJohn state to true if
      // data value equal to false & vice versa
      if (this.state.results[1].value === false) {
        this.setState({ playSoundJohn: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ playSoundJohn: false });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { results, playSoundPeter, playSoundJohn } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {results.map(item => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <div>
                Name: {item.name}
              </div>
              <div>
                Value: {item.value.toString()}
              </div>
              <br />
            </div>
          )
        })}
        <div>
          Peter sound: {(playSoundPeter) ? 'true' : 'false'}
        </div>
        <div>
          John sound: {(playSoundJohn) ? 'true' : 'false'}
        </div>
        {(playSoundPeter) ? <audio src={Sound} autoPlay /> : ''}
        {(playSoundJohn) ? <audio src={Sound} autoPlay /> : ''}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-g6gvtd?embed=1&file=index.js)

At code above if data increases or decreases i must manually add or remove :

1. playSound state
2. conditional statement & setState
3. div true or false value
4. audio sound

How to auto generate sound code if data increases?

Solved **Updated** [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2hwzyd?embed=1&file=index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `<audio ...>` tags here; use `new Audio()` instead
2. Sound isn't concern of `render`, but the concern of `getData` instead

   ```
   class App extends Component {
     state = {
       results: [],
     }

     componentDidMount() {
       this.getData()
       // get data every 5 sec
       setInterval(this.getData, 5000);
     }

     getData = () => {
       // generate random value
       data[0].value = Math.random() >= 0.5;
       data[1].value = Math.random() >= 0.5;

       // set results state to data
       this.setState({ results: data });  

       // your condition here. If John or Peter value is false
       if (data.some(d => d.false)) {
         var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
         audio.play();
       }
     }
   ```

   3. A hint. Assign timer ID to some variable and destroy it in `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: Mr. Asiniy, thank you very much for your answer, i tried and update the demo. but at the point three i don't understand about timer ID, what is the timer ID you mean, is it a number used `setInterval` and `clearInterval`? and are the timer ID place in `componentWillUnmount`?
Can you please look at the updated demo, did i miss something?

Comment: Mr. Asiniy, i still have a little problem from my updated demo. It seems work but have a little different with the first demo. I already update my question and hope you can help to solve them. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry Mr. Asiniy, i have no idea to make timer id. Without timer id it seems works but miss something little different with the first demo.
I already update my question above about the different, because it's to long if i write in this comment.

Can you explain the function of timer id? or if i add timer id it can fix the different issue between first demo and updated demo? I need to fix the different issue. Thank you.

Comment: This became completely different question. Could you rollback your question to the working answer, then accept this answer, then create another question. It will be better

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Asiniy, you solved my question and i will create another question for a little different between first and updated demo.